# Two halves of Java JButton (+/-)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm sorry, but I don't even really know how to phrase this question, because I lack the terminology. Basically, I wanna know how to create this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

In Java, where multiple JButtons take up one space, with a subtle line in between them. Can anyone give me some direction, please? I've searched on my own for a while, and I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: It's not a single button - It's really just multiple buttons with specific layout / borders to make them "look" different

Comment: Thanks, @Krease ! Do you have advice on how to give the JPanel that contains the two buttons a border that looks like a normal JButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct support for what you want.

You could use a `JPanel` with a horizontal `BoxLayout`.

Then you remove the `Border` from each of the buttons by using `setBorder(null)`.

You could then add a `Border` to the panel so it looks like the buttons share the same `Border`.

You can then add a `JSeparator` between each button.

Comment: That's very helpful! I almost have what I want. Do you have advice for how to make the JPanel's border look like a JButton's border?

Comment: You can always override the border drawing code to do whatever you need

Comment: A JButton uses a custom Border that is designed specifically for a JButton so that the state of Border can be changed when a button is clicked etc. The logic won't apply to a panel obviously. The exact Border used by the button will depend on the LAF so it will be hard to duplicate. Since you are essentially creating a custom component you should create your own custom border.

Answer (score 2):

One can create a set of buttons (or other widgets) grouped in a `JToolBar`. There are methods like `setBorderPainted()`, `setFloatable()`, etc., to customize the toolbar properties. Here is a basic example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayGui();
    }
    private static void displayGui() {
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        toolBar.add(saveButton);
        toolBar.add(deleteButton);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My App");
        frame.add(toolBar);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
An example toolbar (image only):

[image]

Comment: That's really creative! But I think the JToolBar causes more problems then it is worth. I like your solution, though!

Comment: Added to the answer an image of the toolbar (created using `JToolBar`) I had created few years back (as an example).